# Not able to create bigquery connection from within spark jar when running on dataproc cluster

Tags: java, apache-spark, jdbc, google-bigquery, dataproc

I want to delete data from bigquery table from within Spark running on dataproc cluster. But I am getting SIGSEGV runtime error when running the Spark application. Here is the full error when trying:

```
 datasource.getConnection()

 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
 SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f218680fc80, pid=25451, tid=0x00007f21f8c20700

 JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_322-b06) (build 1.8.0_322-b06)
 Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.322-b06 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  0x00007f218680fc80
 Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
 An error report file with more information is saved as: /tmp/4f00321a-e1ae-4869-9540-ff789383b27c/hs_err_pid25451.log
 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit: https://github.com/adoptium/adoptium-support/issues
```

This is the sample code that I am following:

```
public class ConnectServiceAuthentication {
public static Connection connectViaDS() throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = null;
    DataSource ds = new 
com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.DataSource();
    ds.setURL("jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;\n" + "OAuthType=3;ProjectId=myProjectid;");
    ds.setProjectId("myProjectid");
    ds.setOAuthType(0); // Service Authentication
ds.setOAuthServiceAcctEmail("myproject_bigquery@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com");
    ds.setOAuthPvtKey("/home/key.json");
    connection = ds.getConnection();
    return connection;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = connectViaDS();
    String sql = "select count(1) from  temp.tempn1;";

    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    if (rs.next())
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
    
    connection.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please share a code snippet of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you following an example? if so, could you provide the link. As mention above, a code above will provide better insight to this case as it will allow us to reproduce your issue. Also, have you try using the recommendation message `Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try ulimit -c unlimited` . I think you should also provide us the detailed log info on `/tmp/4f00321a-e1ae-4869-9540-ff789383b27c/hs_err_pid25451.log`

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the java bigquery client ?
I'm using the client from my Spark Application to insert/update/delete data from BigQuery

Here's [a link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-java)

You would need to add the library into your jar when deploying the application